# How do I switch from terminal back to vim?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal

When I'm in vim and I use :term to open a terminal inside vim, how can I switch back from the terminal to vim?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regular keys bindings of vim splits to move between them as the terminal inside vim is also a split. If you have only 2 splits open(one is your terminal and one is you vim buffer) then you can use **Ctrl-w Ctrl-w** to move back and forth between your terminal and vim. You can know more about how to move between splits in [Here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Switch_between_Vim_window_splits_easily).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!